# how to make a left outer join in following scenario

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables where I want to take employee no from first table and from second table I am taking a file path which may include the employee no.

So I want to take emp no. from first table and want to find that emp no in second tables's file path column by using LIKE keyword.

I need your help.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
select first.employee_no,sec.filepath from Firsttable AS first join Secondtable AS sec
 on first.employee_no=sec.employee_no where first.employee_no like '%empnos%'
```